# jsx print components via array

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to list components on a dashboard screen evenly.
Originally I used just plain `<DayGraph />` to set the component to be loaded in place in the parent.

But now I load all the graph components in a array and use `getOdd` and `getEven` functions to divide the graphs compnents into two arrays with `mod`

Problem is I dont know how to place them correctly now. I just get the correct string in place on screen and not the component.

I think my problem is in `homeNewDashboard` where I print it, but I could be completely wrong here, I just experimented with the idea.

Here is some of the code

I used `'<'+i.DisplayName+'/>'`, but im unsure of this. its is the correct name though. Can it be converted to be seen as the component?

```
getAllGraphs:function(pref){
    //STOP
    var graphs = [];
    if(pref){
        if (pref.graph_ave_pain)  {graphs.push(Graph_Ave_Pain)}
        if (pref.graph_adv_events){graphs.push(Graph_Events)}
        if (pref.graph_epidurals) {graphs.push(Graph_Epidurals)}
        if (pref.graph_modalities){graphs.push(Graph_Modalities)}
        if (pref.graph_surg_type) {graphs.push(Graph_Surgery_Type)}
        if (pref.graph_surg_type) {graphs.push(Graph_Surgeries)}
        if (pref.graph_diag)      {graphs.push(Graph_Diagnosis)}
    }
    return graphs;
},

getOddGraphs: function(pref){
    if(pref.licensecontrol) {
        var graphs = this.getAllGraphs(pref);
        var newArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < graphs.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 > 0) {
                newArray.push(graphs[i]);
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }
},

getEvenGraphs: function(pref){
    if(pref.licensecontrol) {
        var graphs = this.getAllGraphs(pref);
        var newArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < graphs.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                newArray.push(graphs[i]);
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }
},




render () {



        var homeNewDashboard =
            <div>
                <div className="content-main row " style={{marginTop:-45}}>
                    <div className="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                        <div>
                            <DayGraph />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {this.getOddGraphs(pref).map(function (i) {
                                return '<'+i.displayName+'/>';
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to render one of the components that you are pushing to the array:

```
<div>
    {this.getOddGraphs(pref).map(function (Component) {
        return <Component />;
    })}
</div>
```

Something like this should work if your array contains React components. For JSX, the keyword used to render the component must be Capitalized.